# Event doesn't trigger on an input when its added programmatically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, input

Hello StackOverflow,

I'd like to know if there is way to trigger an event after the control (in this case an input textbox) has been added programmatically using jQuery.  What I mean is, I added a row filled with s and inputs to a table using jQUery.after() in a table and the controls in this new row won't trigger any event.

I really need help on this one, I couldn't figure it out after a lot of "googling" and I can't struggle on that anymore.  Some help would be really appreciated.

If it isn't clear enough, don't mind to ask any question to make it clearer.

EDIT (here's what I do to add a row)

```
$(".prodNum").on("change", function(){
                //Envoie le sku du produit au serveur et affiche les infos lorsque le produit est valide
                $.post("../PHP/caisse.php", {productSku : $(this).val()}, 
                    function(data){
                        var total = 0;
                        var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        var newRow = "";

                        if( typeof jsonObj.message !== "undefined")
                        {
                            alert(jsonObj.message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            total = jsonObj.price;

                            $("#desc" + numberOfProducts ).val(jsonObj.description);
                            $("#prix" + numberOfProducts ).val(roundToDecimals(jsonObj.price,2));
                            $("#qte" + numberOfProducts ).val(1);
                            $("#total" + numberOfProducts ).val(roundToDecimals(total,2)).change();

                            newRow = addProductRow(numberOfProducts);

                            $("#prod" + numberOfProducts ).after(newRow);

                            numberOfProducts++;
                        }
                    });
            });
```

And here's addProductRow function

```
function addProductRow(numOfProd)
{
if( numOfProd % 2 == 0 )
{
    newRow = "<tr class=\"alternate1\" id=\"prod" + numOfProd + "\">";
}
else
{
    newRow = "<tr class=\"alternate2\">";
}

newRow += "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\"prodNum\" name=\"prodNum[]\" id = \"prodNum" + (numOfProd + 1) + "\" /></td>";
newRow += "<td class=\"middle\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"desc\" id=\"desc" + (numOfProd + 1) + "\" /></td>";
newRow += "<td class=\"middle\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"price\" id=\"prix" + (numOfProd + 1) + "\" /></td>";
newRow += "<td class=\"middle\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"qty\" id=\"qte" + (numOfProd + 1) + "\" /></td>"; 
newRow += "<td class=\"middle\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"total\" name=\"total[]\" id=\"total" + (numOfProd + 1) + "\" /></td></tr>";

return newRow;
```

}

The result expected is that the new row can use the "change" event on its "prodNum" input.

Thank you,

PBaller

Comment: Can you post some example code or use http://jsfiddle.net to set up an example?  It sounds like you're not binding to the events after you create the new row.

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.7+ use `on`. If not, use `delegate`. This is the third (at least) question that has been asked about this in the last hour alone.

Comment: SoWeLie This is exactly what happens.  I can't bind my event to the input after its creation.  And still don't know how.  I tried @Ghommey solution, but it doesn't work either.  Some help would still be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `live` instead of `bind` - 
Note that of jQuery 1.7, the .`live()` method is deprecated.
So if you are using jQuery 1.7 or later use `.on()` .

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
 // jQuery 1.3+
 $("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });  

 // jQuery 1.4.3+              
 $(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the time it tooks for me to answer, but this solution isn't working for my issue.  I'm sure it actually works for anything else.  Thanks for your help though.  I'll provide a code snippet for further help.